# Multi Search Column Datatables Using Server Side Processing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables, server-side

i want to make individual searching using data tables server side , all function is same with the example in datatables.net , but when i search in column filter box , it just processing and doesnt change , anyone can help me ? thank you :)

for easy read , i will write my code below :

**Controller**

```
public function pm()
    {
        $data['title'] = "PM";
        $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
        $data['user'] = $this->db->select('*')->from('mst_user')->join('mst_pegawai', 'mst_pegawai.username=mst_user.username', 'left')->where('mst_user.username', $username)->get()->row_array();

        $data['dataPM'] = $this->db->get('mfaktur');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/navbar', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/sidebar', $data);
            $this->load->view('master/pm', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
    }
    // Get data perusahaan
    public function get_data_pm()
    {
        $list = $this->pm->get_datatables();
        $data = array();
        $no = $_POST['start'];

        foreach ($list as $field) {
            // $tmbl2 = '<a href="" class="success p-0" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalUpdate"' . $row(['id']) . '"><i class="ft-edit-2 font-medium-3 mr-2"></i></a>';
            $tmbl = "<button href='' class='btn btn-success mb-1' data-toggle='modal' data-backdrop='static' data-keyboard='false' data-target='#ModalUpdate'>Update</button>";
            $no++;
            $row = array();
            $row[] = $no;
            $row[] = $field->kdJenisTransaksi;
            $row[] = $field->fgPengganti;
            $row[] = $field->nomorFaktur;
            $row[] = $field->masaPajak;
            $row[] = $field->tahunPajak;
            $row[] = $field->tanggalFaktur;
            $row[] = $field->npwpPenjual;
            $row[] = $field->alamatPenjual;
            $row[] = $field->namaPenjual;
            $row[] = $field->npwpLawanTransaksi;
            $row[] = $field->namaLawanTransaksi;
            $row[] = $field->alamatLawanTransaksi;
            $row[] = $field->referensi;
            $row[] = $field->jumlahDpp;
            $row[] = $field->jumlahPpn;
            $row[] = $field->jumlahPpnbm;
            $row[] = $field->isWapu;
            $row[] = $field->isSupplierReg;
            $row[] = $field->statusApproval;
            $row[] = $field->statusFaktur;
            $row[] = "<a href='' class='btn btn-success' data-toggle='modal' data-id='" . $field->id . "' data-target='#ModalUpdate2'>Update</a>";

            $data[] = $row;
        }
        $output = array(
            "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
            "recordsTotal" => $this->pm->count_all(),
            "recordsFiltered" => $this->pm->count_filtered(),
            "data" => $data,
        );
        //output dalam format JSON
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

**Model**

```
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

// Export PM
class Pmmaster extends CI_Model
{
    public $table_user = 'mfaktur'; //nama tabel dari database id

    public $column_order = array(null, 'kdJenisTransaksi', 'fgPengganti', 'nomorFaktur', 'masaPajak', 'tahunPajak', 'tanggalFaktur', 'npwpPenjual', 'alamatPenjual', 'namaPenjual', 'npwpLawanTransaksi', 'namaLawanTransaksi', 'alamatLawanTransaksi', 'referensi', 'jumlahDpp', 'jumlahPpn', 'jumlahPpnbm', 'isWapu', 'isSupplierReg', 'statusApproval', 'statusFaktur'); //field yang ada di table user

    public $column_search = array('kdJenisTransaksi', 'fgPengganti', 'nomorFaktur', 'masaPajak', 'tahunPajak', 'npwpPenjual', 'alamatPenjual', 'namaPenjual', 'npwpLawanTransaksi', 'namaLawanTransaksi', 'alamatLawanTransaksi', 'referensi', 'isWapu', 'isSupplierReg', 'statusApproval', 'statusFaktur'); //field yang diizin untuk pencarian

    public $order = array('id' => 'asc'); // default order

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    private function _get_datatables_query()
    {

        $this->db->from($this->table_user);
        $where = "branch_id = CASE WHEN '" . $this->session->userdata('branch_id') . "' = '11' THEN branch_id ELSE '" . $this->session->userdata('branch_id') . "' END";
        $this->db->where($where);

        $i = 0;
        // looping awal
        foreach ($this->column_search as $item) {
            // jika datatable mengirimkan pencarian dengan metode POST
            if ($_POST['search']['value']) {
                // looping awal
                if ($i === 0) {
                    $this->db->group_start();
                    $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                } else {
                    $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }

                if (count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) {
                    $this->db->group_end();
                }
            }
            $i++;
        }

        if (isset($_POST['order'])) {
            $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
        } else if (isset($this->order)) {
            $order = $this->order;
            $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
        }
    }

    public function get_datatables()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        if ($_POST['length'] != -1) {
            $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
        }

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function count_filtered()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }

    public function count_all()
    {
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }

}
```

**View**

```
    <!-- BEGIN : Main Content-->
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="content-overlay"></div>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="content-header"><?=$title?></div>
                    <p class="content-sub-header mb-1">Data <b>PM </b>dalam bentuk tabel.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Hoverable Rows Starts-->
            <section id="hoverable-rows">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h4 class="card-title"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-table mr-2"></i>Data PM</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="flash-updateStatus" data-flashupdatestatus="<?=$this->session->flashdata('message');?>"></div>
                            <?php
                                $message = $this->session->flashdata('message');
                                if (isset($message)) {
                                    $this->session->unset_userdata('message');
                                }
                                ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table id="tabel_all_pm" class="table table-striped table-hover">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                                <th>No</th>
                                                <th>kdJenisTransaksi</th>
                                                <th>fgPengganti</th>
                                                <th>nomorFaktur</th>
                                                <th>masaPajak</th>
                                                <th>tahunPajak</th>
                                                <th>tanggalFaktur</th>
                                                <th>npwpPenjual</th>
                                                <th>alamatPenjual</th>
                                                <th>namaPenjual</th>
                                                <th>npwpLawanTransaksi</th>
                                                <th>namaLawanTransaksi</th>
                                                <th>alamatLawanTransaksi</th>
                                                <th>referensi</th>
                                                <th>jumlahDpp</th>
                                                <th>jumlahPpn</th>
                                                <th>jumlahPpnbm</th>
                                                <th>isWapu</th>
                                                <th>isSupplierReg</th>
                                                <th>statusApproval</th>
                                                <th>statusFaktur</th>
                                                <th>Aksi</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                        </tbody>
                                        <tfoot>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>No</th>
                                                <th>kdJenisTransaksi</th>
                                                <th>fgPengganti</th>
                                                <th>nomorFaktur</th>
                                                <th>masaPajak</th>
                                                <th>tahunPajak</th>
                                                <th>tanggalFaktur</th>
                                                <th>npwpPenjual</th>
                                                <th>alamatPenjual</th>
                                                <th>namaPenjual</th>
                                                <th>npwpLawanTransaksi</th>
                                                <th>namaLawanTransaksi</th>
                                                <th>alamatLawanTransaksi</th>
                                                <th>referensi</th>
                                                <th>jumlahDpp</th>
                                                <th>jumlahPpn</th>
                                                <th>jumlahPpnbm</th>
                                                <th>isWapu</th>
                                                <th>isSupplierReg</th>
                                                <th>statusApproval</th>
                                                <th>statusFaktur</th>
                                                <th>Aksi</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tfoot>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
    <!--Hoverable rows Ends-->
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- END : End Main Content-->

<div class="modal fade text-left" id="ModalUpdate2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalUpdateLabel8" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-success">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="ModalUpdateLabel8"><i class="ft-user-plus mr-2"></i>Update Status Faktur</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="ft-x font-medium-2 text-bold-700"></i></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form class="" action="<?=base_url('master/updateStatus');?>" method="post">
                <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label><span style="color:red;">*</span> STATUS FAKTUR SAAT INI : </label>
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" readonly>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="statusFaktur" name="statusFaktur" readonly>
                        <?=form_error('username', '<small class="text-danger">', '</small>')?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label><span style="color:red;">*</span> STATUS FAKTUR DARI DJP : </label>
                        <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" id="url" name="url" readonly> -->
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="statusFakturBaru" name="statusFakturBaru" readonly>
                        <?=form_error('username', '<small class="text-danger">', '</small>')?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn bg-light-success" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">UPDATE</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <!-- END : Modalbox Add new menu-->
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
  $('#tabel_all_pm tfoot th').each(function() {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
  });

  var table = $('#tabel_all_pm').dataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": url +"master/get_data_pm",
    initComplete: function() {
      var api = this.api();

      // Apply the search
      api.columns().every(function() {
        var that = this;

        $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function() {
          if (that.search() !== this.value) {
            that
              .search(this.value)
              .draw();
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The values you enter into each column search field should automatically be added to the request data which DataTables sends from the browser to your PHP server code, whenever you perform a search, sort, or paging action. Take a look at the [sent parameters](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters) fields - and see the `columns[i][search][value]` fields. These fields will contain your column search values. You can check the request data in your browser, or by inspecting it in your PHP code.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).